# Upsert Revisited

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, relational-database

Suppose I have a very  simple class:

```
public class State
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

where StateId is the auto generated primary key.  StateName and County are a unique key.   Suppose you want to insert a new State for a given StateName and Country if it is not already in the db.   Various solutions proposed in other similar questions do not work here:

```
State state = new State{StateName="New York", Country="US"};

db.States.add(state);  //Does not work because we can get a unique key violation.

db.States.addOrUpdate(state); does not work because the primary key is not known.
```

finally the most promising one:

```
var stateQuery = from state in db.States
                 where StateName = "New York"
                 and Country = "US"
                 select state;
State newState = stateQuery.FirstOrDefault();
if(newState != null) return newState;
newState = new State{StateName="New York", Country="US"}
db.States.add(newState)
return newState;
//does not work because it can generate a unique key violoation if there are
//concurrent upserts.
```

I have examined the other questions concerning upserts in entity framework and still don't have a satisfactory answer for this question.  Is there a way to do this without getting a unique key violation assumming concurrent upserts are occuring coming from clients on different machines?  How can this be handled so as to not produce an exception?

Comment: Use the last approach. But *you always have to catch the unique key violation*. If it occurs, fetch the existing state from the database. In the end, only the database can guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

"AddOrUpdate" and your second scenario check if the row already exists or not when you call the method/query and not during the "SaveChanges" which is a issue for concurrents upsert like you noticed.

There is some solution but they can all only be done when you call SaveChanges:

**Using a lock (Web Application)**

Using a lock and your second scenario to make sure 2 users cannot try to add a state at the same time. *Recommended if it can fit in your scenario.*

```
lock(stateLock)
{
    using(var db = new MyContext)
    {
        var state = (from state in db.States
                         where StateName = "New York"
                         and Country = "US"
                         select state).FirstOrDefault();

        if(state == null)
        {
            State newState = new State{StateName="New York", Country="US"}
            db.States.add(newState)
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

- Create a custom SQL Command for this case
- Try/Catch row by row

  - Ugly but it work
- Lock + Global Context for only a few special kind of entities (Web Application).

  - Coding horror approach but it work
- BulkMerge using your own "Primary Key" using: http://entityframework-extensions.net/

  - PAID but it work

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the Entity Framework Extensions project.

**Edit 1**

AddOrUpdate approach will never work since it take the decision to "Add" or "Update" when the method is invoked. However, a concurrent user can still insert a similar value (unique key) between the AddOrUpdate and SaveChanges call.

Lock approach only work for web application so I guess it will not fit either in your scenario.

You are left with 3 solutions (at least from my post):

- Create a custom SQL for this case (*Recommanded*)
- Try/Catch row by row
- Use BulkMerge

**Edit 2**: Adding some scenario

Let take a simple example which 2 users do the same thing

```
using(var ctx = new EntitiesContext()) 
{
    State state = new State{StateName="New York", Country="US"};

    // SELECT TOP (2) * FROM States WHERE (N'New York' = StateName) AND (N'US' = Country)
    ctx.States.AddOrUpdate(x => new {x.StateName, x.Country }, state);

    // INSERT: INSERT INTO States VALUES (...); SELECT ID 
    // UPDATE: Perform an update on different column value retrieved from AddOrUpdate
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

*Case 1:*

This case work fine since no concurrent save happened

- UserA: AddOrUpdate() // Nothing found => ADD
- UserA: SaveChanges() // Add with PK = 10
- UserB: AddOrUpdate() // Data found, SET PK to 10 => UPDATE
- UserB: SaveChanges() // Update data

*Case 2:*

This case fail, you need to catch the error and do something

- UserA: AddOrUpdate() // Nothing found => ADD
- UserB: AddOrUpdate() // Nothing found => ADD
- UserA: SaveChanges() // Add with PK = 10
- UserB: SaveChanges() // Oops! Unique Key Violation error

**Merge / BulkMerge**

Merge from SQL is created to support concurrent UPSERT:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb510625.aspx

By example with BulkMerge (which perform a SQL Merge), concurrent UPSERT will not cause any error.

```
using(var ctx = new EntitiesContext()) 
{
    List<State> states = new List<State>();
    states.Add(new State{StateName="New York", Country="US"});
    // ... add thousands of states and more! ...

    ctx.BulkMerge(states, operation => 
        operation.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new {x.StateName, x.Country});
}
```

**Edit 3**

You are right, merge require some isolation to reduce even more or to none the chance of conflict.

Here is a single entity approach. With a double “AddOrUpdate”, it almost impossible the code fail to concurrent add however, this code is not generic and make 3-4 database roundtrip so this is not recommend to use everywhere but only for few kind of entities.

```
using (var ctx = new TestContext())
{
    // ... code ...

    var state = AddOrUpdateState(ctx, "New York", "US");

    // ... code ...

    // Save other entities
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}

public State AddOrUpdateState(TestContext context, string stateName, string countryName)
{
    State state = new State{StateName = stateName, Country = countryName};

    using (var ctx = new TestContext())
    {
        // WORK 99,9% of times
        ctx.States.AddOrUpdate(x => new {x.StateName, x.Country }, state);

        try
        {
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // WORK for the 0.1% time left 
            // Call AddOrUpdate to get properties modified
            ctx.States.AddOrUpdate(x => new {x.StateName, x.Country }, state);
            ctx.SaveChanges();

            // There is still have a chance of concurrent access if 
            // A thread delete this state then a thread add it before this one,
            // But you probably have better chance to have GUID collision then this...
        }
    }

    // Attach entity to current context if necessary
    context.States.Attach(state);
    context.Entry(state).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

    return state;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your comment about AddOrUpdate: Since I don't know the primary key (it is auto generated) will AddOrUpdate even work? Your lock approach only works if there is only one client process.  Correct?

Comment: @danb With AddOrUpdate , you can specific a predicate to use instead of the primary key

Comment: You are right, by bad! Long time I have not used this method, however you still have the same issue. AddOrUpdate take the decision about adding or updating when you call the method which can cause error if similar value has been added between this call and SaveChanges call.

Comment: @ESG AddOrUpdate still requires that I would have to know  the primary key but that is not known here.

Comment: AddOrUpdate doesn't require to know the primary key if used by a predicate. If the entity exists, the primary key will be retrieved from the database and an update will be performed otherwise the entity will be added.

Comment: @JonathanMagnan can you show me what you mean code wise?

Comment: @JonathanMagnan  I am really looking for how to do this, without a third party extension.   Can you explain how bulk merge gets around the concurrency issue? Are you using transaction serializable

Comment: @JonathanMagnan I think edit three is better, however, you are catching all exceptions which may not be so good(for example if there is a network issue).  Also you are trying only one more time, which still may not work under high load rates.  Are you also accounting  for the possibility of deletes happening? Have you seen this: http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/

Comment: @JonathanMagnan Thanks for taking the time to look at this. I wish I could have awarded you the bounty, but I think your solution required more work (as per the link to the article in my comment above).  I must admit I am surprised it did not get more attention.  Perhaps entity framework isnt popular or maybe it was something about my question.

Comment: No problem, it was fun to visiting upsert ;) I believe however you try to add to much complexity with "network issue" and if a "delete" happen. You doesn't add this kind of logic to your "select" or other "save changes" so why doing it to "upsert".